# When does a sum of two diffeomorphism still result in a diffeomorphism?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose I have $f, g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. 
Suppose $f$ and $g$ restricted to $U$ are both diffeomorphisms. I was wondering when does $f+g$ define a diffeomorphism on $U$? Is there a nice condition for this? Thank you.

Comment: Note that even if $f$ and $g$ are invertible functions, $f + g$ may not be invertible at all.  As an example, take $U$ to be the unit disk centered at the origin, $f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = - x$.

Comment: Right, that's why I was wondering if there was any condition that I can put on $f$ and $g$ like they are linearly independent (which probably is not enough) or something so that I can guarantee that the sum is still a diffeomorphism

Comment: $f,g$ linearly independent is not enough (just modify it on a smaller ball for example).  I suppose you can say: if $g$ is $C^1$-small enough, then $f+g$ is a diffeomorphism onto image.

Comment: @user10354138 What does "$C^1$-small enough" mean?

Comment: It has a small enough $C^1$-norm on $U$.  Essentially, the inverse function theorem.